# (Terraform, GCP) Error 403: Permission denied to list services for consumer container [projects/335478934851]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam

On **GCP**, I'm trying to enable **"Identity and Access Management (IAM) API"** with this **Terraform** code below:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-173831"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_project_service" "project" {
  service = "iam.googleapis.com"
}
```

But I got this error:

> Error when reading or editing Project Service : Request `List Project Services myproject-173831` returned error: Failed to list enabled
> services for project myproject-173831: googleapi: Error 403:
> Permission denied to list services for consumer container
> [projects/335478934851]

Then, I couldn't enable it

[image]

So now, I'm trying to add a role to solve this error above but there are too many roles to choose:

[image]

What role do I need to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the role **"Quota Administrator"**:

[image]

Then, apply your **Terraform** code again:

```js
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("myCredentials.json")
  project     = "myproject-173831"
  region      = "asia-northeast1"
}

resource "google_project_service" "project" {
  service = "iam.googleapis.com"
}
```

Finally, you can enable **"Identity and Access Management (IAM) API"**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with answer 1 but a few additions:

1. Comment recommends `roles/servicemanagement.quotaViewer`, this is insufficient for the terraform resource `google_project_service`.
2. Required roles I have made it work with are:

- Quota Administrator (`roles/servicemanagement.quotaAdmin`)
- Service Usage Admin (`roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin`)

3. Sometimes it takes a few minutes to enable services and it is worth retrying after a failed run to see if the services are now enabled.
4. I would also recommend batch enabling services in their own resource/module using the pattern shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67210655/20935894).